# How to provide authentication for a single user (Node, Express)?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication

I am currently working on an app with a React frontend and a Node/Express backend. There are certain functions of the app that I only want an admin user to be able to use, so I want to implement an admin login form that takes a username and password. This would be the only user that this app has.

How would I go about implementing this? I've looked at technologies like passport.js and express-basic-auth, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to implement this since there is only a single user. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it by yourself then whenever the user logs in the application, create an authtoken for the user and save it in the backend and send the authoken as the response for successful login. Further save the authtoken as a cookie on the frontend. Next will be while performing any action you need to send the authtoken to the server. If that authtoken is present on the server side you go on with the action or else send the response error saying that the authtoken is invalid of something like that. On loggin out of the application remember to expire the cookie and also remove the authtoken from the backend.

You can add this if you want where if the authoken provided is incorrect you can simple remove the authtoken from the backend and redirect the user to login page expiring the cookie from the frontend.